# Error “buffer is too small for requested array” when run .mat file with scipy.io python

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I try to run .mat files in python using scipy.io. at first its works with no problems, now when I run the .mat files again show me the following error "Error “buffer is too small for requested array”.
anyone can help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to see how to ask a good question that is more likely to get answered, and update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we have the information we need to be able to help.

Comment: Normally we ask for the full traceback.  That may or may not help.  It might also help to know what has changed.  Are you reading new larger files?  In a different script?  More stuff in memory?  Have you gone back and tried previous files and environment.  It's certainly possible to load/create arrays that are too large for memory.  Either they are very large, or other large arrays are already taking up space.  Memory problems are hard to diagnose remotely.